# Excel macro that sort data by a given column then at change of the column value x, it removes duplication in column y

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to develop a macro that sort data by column B, then at change of value in column B, it gives a total sum of data in column E,F and K after Removes duplication in column K, that are also at the change of value in C.

Example:

[image: Example]

Sorting by column B will group manifest numbers together and we work total for columns E,F per each manifest.
While on K, the column C data would have already be grouped by waybill numbers, such that every row with the same waybill number contains the same Freight cost in K. so for every waybill we want only one value in column k which can be the first entry per waybill.
so we need to remove the duplication for every waybill.
then we finally get the total freight per manifest long with columns E and F.
we then insert 2 blank rows at the change of each manifest in B.

[image: manual solution]

please need help this is what i have done so far.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B3:B771"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:K771")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5, 6, 11) _
        , Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=True, SummaryBelowData:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: ① There are too many things in your post and no clear question. It looks like a *"Please do my work, I can't do it."* question. So try to ask a well defined clear question and not multiple questions at once. Reading [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) might help you. ② Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: thank, for cleaning out